# How can I add Composer to an existing site?

Tags: 9, composer

I have a site running on Drupal 9.3.15 installed from the zip file.

I want to use composer and I followed [Add Composer to an existing site[1](https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal/add-composer-to-an-existing-site), but I get this error message.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in ../vendor/drupal/core-vendor-hardening/Config.php on [line 142](https://github.com/drupal/core-vendor-hardening/blob/9.3.x/Config.php#L142)

The code causing the error is the following one.

```php
// Merge root config with defaults.
foreach (array_change_key_case(static::$defaultConfig, CASE_LOWER) as $package => $paths) {
  $this->configData[$package] = array_merge(
    $this->configData[$package] ?? [],
    $paths);
  }
```

I don't know where the error is.

The differences I find between a site installed with Composer and one installed from a zip file is that projects installed with Composer use the web folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Do not screenshot code because it is not searchable.  Instead, cut-and-paste the code and use the formatting tool on this site to make it easier to read.

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: I use php version 7.4

Comment: Your screenshot is not correct, see https://github.com/drupal/core-vendor-hardening/blob/9.3.15/Config.php#L142

Comment: And this might be a PHP version problem. You probably have two PHP versions installed, one for the web server and a different one for the command line.

Comment: Yes, I have two versions of PHP, one for cpanel and one for the drupal host.
Is there anything that can be done to fix this problem? 
The cpanel is very useful to me but it operates with a version lower than php7.4

Comment: I'm going to check the screenshot and upload the code, now that you mention it I don't know what happened but the example you mention seems familiar to me.

Comment: yes, I have noticed it is correct, I deleted line 142 to paste it in another text.

Answer (score 2):

The linked documentation says:

> **For sites created on Drupal 8.8.0 or later**
>
> Even if you installed Drupal 8.8.0 from the tarball, Composer was
> pre-installed. So you should be able to manage your site using
> Composer without taking any extra steps to convert the site.

So `composer` can be used right away.

The line accidentally removed in the screenshot contains the `??` operator, which was introduced in PHP 7. An older PHP version causes a syntax error.

Check `php -v`. If this is an older version you need to fix this. You can't just run the composer binary with a different PHP version, because composer runs scripts like Config.php in a separate environment which uses whatever is linked in `/usr/bin/php`.

In Debian/Ubuntu systems you can configure the linked php version:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

---

Alternatively, if your Linux doesn't have this tool to manage symbolic links or you don't have permissions to do this globally, you can create the symbolic link for a local account:

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/php7.4 ~/bin/php

nano ~/.bashrc
```

in `.bashrc` add the new directory at the beginning of the variable PATH (where Linux searches for executables):

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: The screenshot error was made on a copy of the config.php file, the original is like the one you suggested.
The system is linux and Drupal  is operating with php 7.4
To use composer with php7.4 I configured composer with the command
'/usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/composer.phar update'
The version drupal I use is 9.3.15 updated from version 9.2 which was installed from a zip file.
According to the guide I should be able to use composer directly but it gives me the error ?? on line 142

Comment: Drupal 9 requires PHP 7.3 which includes the Drupal composer scripts. As said running the composer binary with /usr/bin/php7.4 is not sufficient. You need the symbolic link /usr/bin/php pointing at /usr/bin/php7.4. If your linux doesn't have update-alternatives or similar to manage the symbolic links then simply replace the symbolic link.