# install Drush on shared server

Tags: drush

please i need to use drush on  shared server

i allready use composer foe install drush,,

but if i use sudo command

sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

, it is give me this massage

> -bash: sudo: command not found

i allready contact the server customer serves

and the answer was

we cannot support and sudo commnds

any IDEAS please for using drush on shaired server

Comment: `sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush` moves the Drush executable to a path that lets you invoke it by calling `drush`. This was the case [for Drush 8 and older](https://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/) but is [no longer supported in Drush 9 and newer](https://www.drush.org/latest/install/). Instead, you install Drush locally with the project and invoke it via `vendor/bin/drush`.

Comment: You can still call `drush` when using the [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher). If you don't have sudo privilege see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311773/how-can-i-add-composer-to-an-existing-site how to install a binary in ~/bin.

Answer (score 4):

Execute Drush out of the vendor directory as `vendor/bin/drush`. That is all you need to do. Shared hosting will never allow you to place executables in `/usr/local`.

Comment: yes thats what they say , im looking for anther way to use drush

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your question because we do not understand it.

Comment: I think this answer is pretty clear. There is no need to move Drush in a different directory that is only accessible from the root user.

Answer (score -2):

i found the answer for my issue

we should use the command from the website directory

and use

> vendor/bin/drush

not only

> drush

after > vendor/bin/drush we can put the drush command and injoy by using it

thanks every one for help

Comment: That is what the already given answer said: *Execute Drush out of the vendor directory as `vendor/bin/drush`.*