Execute drush command with specifying php version
We have upgraded the drush to 13.3.2 with Drupal 10.3.6 and PHP 8.3 and we have multiple PHP versions on the server/system with the default PHP version set as 8.1.2. Earlier drush 12.x was being used.
Before upgrading to drush 13, We were able to execute the drush command mentioning PHP version like
/usr/bin/php8.2 <path-to-project-root>/vendor/bin/drush command
but after upgrading to drush 13, the command /usr/bin/php8.3 <path-to-project-root>/vendor/bin/drush command is not executing instead it is giving script as output below
# Support bash to support `source` with fallback on $0 if this does not run with bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006505/6512
selfArg="$BASH_SOURCE"
if [ -z "$selfArg" ]; then
    selfArg="$0"
fi

self=$(realpath $selfArg 2> /dev/null)
if [ -z "$self" ]; then
    self="$selfArg"
fi

dir=$(cd "${self%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd '../drush/drush' && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

export COMPOSER_RUNTIME_BIN_DIR="$(cd "${self%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; pwd)"

# If bash is sourcing this file, we have to source the target as well
bashSource="$BASH_SOURCE"
if [ -n "$bashSource" ]; then
    if [ "$bashSource" != "$0" ]; then
        source "${dir}/drush" "$@"
        return
    fi
fi

"${dir}/drush" "$@"


We tried adding the export in .bashrc file mentioned in documentation, but that also did work, and produced the same output.
UPDATE
Added PATH in .bashrc file as export PATH="/usr/bin/php8.3:$PATH"  which does not update the PHP version.
Added alias in .bashrc file as alias php='/usr/bin/php8.3, which update and show php as 8.3.13. but the result is the same as above for the php <path-to-project-root>/vendor/bin/drush command where php is set to 8.3 from the alias. But now if we try to execute the drush (<path-to-project-root>/vendor/bin/drush) command without the php. It shows Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are running 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18. 
which php shows the output as /usr/bin/php and never points to php8.1 even with the alias or export PATH added in .bashrc file

According to the Drush documentation, the only supported was is to edit the PATH in the shell and call vendor/bin/drush. This question needs to be updated indicating exactly what you have done. Additionally it should show the output of which php. For this to work as expected the PHP binary should show the one you want.

@monalisa Updated the question

You didn’t do all I asked.

I see in the last error message you are using Unbuntu. Try sudo update-alternatives --config php

@4uk4 Yes, we are using Ubuntu, and we can't use sudo update-alternatives --config php to change the default version of PHP as it is a shared server and has other sites running with minimum PHP 8.1 as a requirement.

OK, then don't use an alias and put the symlink to the correct PHP binary version in a local bin folder. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/311790/47547

In case this isn't obvious you have to rehash the shell config or open a new shell for shell startup configurations changes to take effect.
